# Can I switch between formats for DateTimeFormatterBuilder?

Tags: java, parsing, groovy, datetime-format

I'm using DateTimeFormatterBuilder() to turn the JSON data I take in (the commented code) and convert them into one of two formats. To decide which format to use, I'm using a REGEX to find any instances of a square, [] , bracket (with anything inside " .*? " ). After choosing the correct format, I would parse the new value into another JSON object.

The problem is, my program either does not correctly choose which format to use (either a REGEX and method error), or doesn't format it correctly (formatting error), not sure which, and sends an error back (bottom of code), instead.

However, this is only for data that has square brackets. Data without square brackets gets processed correctly. I'm wondering if there are any solutions/suggestions to fix this?

```
// 2018-11-28T13:09:00.2-04:00
def utcDateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .appendFraction(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0, 3, true)
                .appendPattern("xxx")
                .toFormatter()

// 2018-11-28T13:09:00.528-08:00[America/New_York]
def utcDateFormatterWithZone = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                .appendFraction(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0, 3, true)
                .appendPattern("xxx'['VV']'")
                .toFormatter()


if (json.beginDateTime.find("\\[.*?\\]") == true) {
                object.setDate(LocalDateTime.parse("${json.beginDateTime}", utcDateFormatterWithZone).format(outFormatter))
            } else {
                object.setDate(LocalDateTime.parse("${json.beginDateTime}", utcDateFormatter).format(outFormatter))
            }

Error: Text '2019-09-26T15:01:07.941-05:00[America/New_York]' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 29
```

Comment: first problem in your code that `CharSequence.find(regex)` returns String, but you comparing it to true (boolean). remove `==true`. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#find(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Thanks! There was more to it, like LocalDateTime should have been ZonedDateTime, but the null check was part of it.

Answer (score 1):

### This is built-in:  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME

This can be done a lot more easily. The built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` matches both of your formats.

```
    String stringWithoutZoneId = "2018-11-28T13:09:00.2-04:00";
    String stringWithZoneId = "2018-11-28T13:09:00.528-08:00[America/New_York]";

    LocalDateTime parsedWithoutZoneId = LocalDateTime.parse(
            stringWithoutZoneId, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(parsedWithoutZoneId);
    LocalDateTime parsedWithZoneId = LocalDateTime.parse(
            stringWithZoneId, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(parsedWithZoneId);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 2018-11-28T13:09:00.200
> 2018-11-28T13:09:00.528
> ```

### Use the offset too

A word of warning, though: Are you sure you want to ignore the offsets in the strings? With those offsets the strings represent unambiguous points in time. What you get from parsing into `LocalDateTime` are datetimes belonging at different unknown offsets. I can’t see how you can reliably use them for anything useful.

Consider parsing into `ZonedDateTime`. The one-arg `ZonedDateTIme.parse` will even do this without any explicit formatter. Then either store these `ZonedDateTime` directly in your objects or convert to `Instant` and store those. An `Instant` represents a point in time. If you cannot change the type stored, you will probably want to convert your `ZonedDateTime` to UTC (or another agreed-upon time zone), then convert to `LocalDateTime`. All of this said without knowing your real requirements, so I could be wrong, only I think not.

### What went wrong in your code?

@daggett is correct: `CharSequence.find` returns a string, so for you `if` statement to work you would have needed:

```
    if (json.beginDateTime.find("\\[.*?\\]") != null) {
```

A `String` can never be equal to `true`, so the formatter without zone was always chosen.

### Link

[Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)